# converting a utility class to multithreaded class

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a utility class in Java which is accessing a big file system to access a file.
Some files are huge so whats happening is that the `Utility` class is talking a lot of time to access these files and i am facing a performance issue here.
I plan to implement Multithreading to improve performance but i am bit confused as to how i need to do that. below is the structure of the Utility class.

```
public class Utility {

     public static void Method1(ArrayList values){
          //do some processing
          for(int i=0; i< values.size();i++){
             ArrayList<String> details= MethodAccessFileSystem();

             CreateFileInDir(details);
        } 
     }
     public ArrayList<String> MethodAccessFileSystem(){
        //Code to access the file system. This is taking hell lot of time.
     }
     public void CreateFileInDir(ArrayList<String> values){
       //Do some processing here. 
     }
}
```

I used to call this Utilty class in a standalone class using the following syntax

```
       Utility.Method1(values); //values is an ArayList.
```

Now i need to convert the above code into a Multithreaded code.
I know how to create a thread by extending Thread class or implementing a Runnable.
I have a basic idea about that.

But what i need to know is should i convert this whole Utilty class to implement Runnable.
or should parts of the Utilty class needs to seperated and made as Runnable task.
My issue is with the for() loop as these methods are called in loop.
if i separate out MethodAccessFileSystem() and make it as a task will this work.
If MethodAccessFileSystem() is taking a time then will the JVM automaticaly start another thread if i use a Threadpoolexecutor to schedule a fixed number of threads.
Should i need to suspend this method or it is not required or JVM will take care.
The main issue is with the For loop.

At the end what i need is that the Utility class should be Multithreaded and the call to method should be the same as the above.

```
     Utility.Method1(values); //values is an ArayList.
```

I am thinking as to how i can implement that.
Can you please help me with this and provide your suggestions and feedback on the design changes that need to be made.

Thanks
Vikeng

Comment: Do you simply want to allow `Method1` to return before all the values have been processed?

Comment: Ted i need to return Method1 after all values have been processed

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that using multiple threads will speed up what's happening in `MethodAccessFileSystem`? If the problem is disk I/O, then multithreading could (and probably would) make the problem worse, not better.

Comment: Ted my main concern is MethodAccessFileSystem() which is currently taking close to 5 min for a single call. And file to be fetched is close to 1 GB. the Utility is slowing down a lot and my code reviewers are telling me to implement threading. i am not that much concerned about disk I/O as of now.

Comment: You should push back with your code reviewers. If `Utility.Method1` must block until processing has finished, then you need to understand where the time is going before prescribing a solution. If the 5 minutes is spent mostly with I/O operations, then threading will make things worse. If it's spent doing cpu-intensive stuff after fetching the file, then threading must be done in the right way or you will again make things worse instead of better. It would help to know what goes on inside `MethodAccessFileSystem`.

Answer (score 0):

From your class According to me the `chunk of work which fits in Parallelism principle is below loop`.

```
// do some processing
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ArrayList<String> details = MethodAccessFileSystem();
                CreateFileInDir(details);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Amit thanks.But my doubt here is that since this is in a for() loop if MethodAccessFileSystem() & reateFileInDir(details) are busy accessing File system will the for loop get incremented automatically so that he next thread can start by itself. is this possible

Comment: You forgot, I think, to call `start()` on each thread. @vikeng21 - if the code is corrected to call `start()`, then each thread is created and started, and the loop continues. So all threads will have a chance to start. However, for the same reason, Method1 can return before the threads are finished. You would need to follow the above loop with another loop that calls `join()` for each thread.

Answer (score 0):

Before you make the change make sure that multiple threads will help.  Run the method and as best you can check CPU and disk i/o activity.  Also check to see if there's any garbage collection going on.

If any of those conditions exist then adding threads really won't help.  You'll have to address that specific condition in order to get any throughput improvements.

Having said that the trick to making the code thread safe is to not have any instance variables on the class that are used to hold state during the method execution.  For each existing instance variable, you need to decide whether to make it a local variable declared within the method or a method parameter.

Comment: There are other reasons than throughput that OP might want this method to not block. For instance, it may be locking up the UI.

Comment: @Ted Hopp: Absolutely.  Thanks. That's another common bottleneck.  I was really just trying to point out that multithreading is not necessarily the answer.

Comment: Ted,Chris since there is a performance bottleneck i will have to implement threading. Any suggestions on the solution Amit has provided below or something similar...